# How to set Preferences 's default value of checkbox

Tags: android, preferences

My app has preference which has checkbox and it's default value is "unchecked"

How can I set it to "check"?

```
<CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="checkbox6"
        android:title="setting"
        android:defaultValue="true"
    />
```

and it still doesn't "check" at the first time what should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your preference:

```
android:defaultValue="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`android:defaultValue`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html).

Answer (score 0):

What about having preference with such key set to `true`? Or maybe you need `android:defaultValue` attribute.